# How to select faces inside model?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, faces

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bj5Lvb_T81Y) the author selects only faces inside of the model. In my case, I can't select only inside. I am using border select.

[image]

Is there any way to select faces inside without selecting faces on the surface?

Here is my file:

http s://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-tV3odolwlaTM1bjZLRDF6U1Evv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, but first, change triangles to quads by selecting all faces and pressing ALT+J in edit mode.Here is what you can do to select only inside faces:

1. Hide the rim, select one inside face, CTRL+L to select linked.
2. Mark seam around the rim, select one inside face and CTRL (it doesn't work with vertices, must be with faces)

Answer (score 0):

Just change from Wireframe view to Solid View. After you select you can turn the view back to Wireframe. This allows you to not select "through"  the mesh, and thus gives more control. You will need to navigate to the inside of the mesh from the 3D view to select the inside faces.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the askers question. Switching from wireframe to solid and back won't do anything.  If it still makes sense to you, try to elaborate or provide pictures

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select Interior Faces in the Select Menu]

The file is no longer there, but there is a dedicated function for Selecting Interior Geometry: it is aptly named **Select Interior Faces** and you can find it under *Select > Select All by Trait > Interior Faces*