# How to point and select mesh containing face if model contains many meshes?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

Other questions [like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66344/how-to-select-faces-inside-model) are similar but don't address the problem of how to select a particular mesh if there are many meshes in a model.

For instance, this model (https://poly.google.com/view/6mRHqTCZHxw) contains many meshes.

[image]

One way to find the mesh corresponding to the helmet is to manually select each mesh in the *Outliner* editor (top of right-hand bar) until the helmet gets highlighted. This is tedious.

Is there a way to click on the helmet and identify the corresponding mesh?

Comment: What is not good enough about Ctrl+L (select linked) shown in the linked answer? Works exactly as described in your question (at least for now)

Comment: @MrZak thanks! because that didn't seem to work unless the right mesh was selected in the first place? in other words, if the leg mesh was selected, Ctrl+L didn't (seem to) select the helmet mesh.

Comment: Ctrl+L selects the mesh which is linked to the geometry already selected. So if leg mesh is selected Ctrl+L will select whole leg mesh, that's the general idea of this operator. To make it work on helmet in the same way select at least one vertex of helmet. Or use L operator and hover your mouse over what you want to select

Comment: @MrZak found the problem and posted an answer, probably obvious to experts but definitely not obvious to new users! Thanks again!

Comment: Now I see - you were talking about selection in Object mode. I was talking about Edit mode. In Object mode you can also Right click with Alt pressed and get pop up with names of the objects under mouse position. The reason I thought you were working in Edit mode is that you mentioned meshes, and in Blender terms mesh is a datablock in the object datablock. So mesh is available in Edit mode, object - in Object mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure you're in Object Mode.

2) Right-click on any part of the model, and the corresponding mesh should get highlighted.